# What kind of curve is this called and what is the best way to calculate it?

Tags: curves

I am actually a programmer, not hugely expert in math, trying to draw smooth curves between points. I was wondering if any one knows the curve equation that is typically used in roads and railways to connect two different altitudes whilst keeping a smooth gradient between the two...

This is a visual of what i mean:

[image]

As you can guess the top one is unacceptable for a road or train as its too angular.

Poor quality drawing i admit, but i am wondering what kinda equation would generate a curve shown in the bottom of the picture when you know two points (x,y,z) and (x',y',z') ?

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little more clearly?  Which curve is the problem curve?  The bottom green one?  The top one?  I'm missing details.  Most generally, when a curve is fitted to several data points, one usually uses a polynomial fit or a spline curve.  Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).

Comment: The general name for curves like these is sigmoid function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: @EthanMacBrough had a quick fiddle with it, is it possible to get sigmoid function normalized from (-1,-1) to (1,1) though ? See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7jnlhlqv8m   is it not possible to get it precise?

Comment: @WDUK the standard sigmoid functions typically go from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,1)$, so all you need to do is replace $f(x)$ with $2f(x)-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For roads and railways in particular, the important principle is to design a track whose [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) has no sudden changes; for example, you don't want to just attach a quarter-circle to a straight segment (like you see in some wooden toys, for example).

Here's the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_transition_curve).

---

Here's an example (13.3, #60) from James Stewart's *Calculus*:

> Let's consider the problem of designing a railroad track to make a smooth transition between sections of straight track. Existing track along the negative x-axis is to be joined smoothly to a track along the line $y=1$ for $x\geq1$.
>
> (a) Find a polynomial $P=P(x)$ of degree $5$ such that the function defined by is continuous and has continuous slope and continuous
>   curvature.

The idea is to use the curvature formula for plane curves
$$\kappa(x) = \frac{|f''(x)|}{[1+(f'(x))^2]^{3/2}}.$$

Now, with $P(x) = a_5x^5 + a_4x^4 + \cdots + a_0$, you have six unknowns. There are six things that need to match up: the position of each endpoint, the first derivative at each endpoint, and the curvature at each endpoint.

This will give you a system of six equations; solving for the $a_i$, you'll get $P(x)=6a^5-15a^4+10a^3$. (Try graphing this to confirm that it makes a nice transition, or *transfer curve*.)

Comment: Yes i use perfect arcs for lateral movement though i don't adjust radius over time for the Euler spiral i don't quite understand how to do that when interpolating from A to B.

Comment: @WDUK I edited to include an example. The key is the curvature formula. If you use some kind of sigmoidal function or cubic spline, as others have suggested, you could try to work in the curvature in a similar way to the example problem here.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary piece-wise smooth curves I recommend [cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) since they're versatile and can approximate any curve you'd use in application.